Direct sum possible if $\ker(L)$ and $\mathrm{im} (L)$ both contain odd terms?
I am working with the vector space $V = \mathbb{C}[x]$ (polynomials with complex coefficients) and a linear operator $L: V \to V$ defined by:
$$
L(p(x)) = (x-1)(p(x) + p(-x)).
$$
The kernel $\ker(L)$ consists of odd polynomials, with a basis:
$$
   \{x, x^3, x^5, \dots\}, \quad \text{which can be expressed as } x^{2n+1}.
   $$
The image $\operatorname{im}(L)$ consists of polynomials of the form $(x-1)q(x)$, where $q(x)$ is an even polynomial. A basis for $\operatorname{im}(L)$ is:
$$
   \{2(x-1), 2(x-1)x^2, 2(x-1)x^4, \dots\}, \quad \text{which can be expressed as } 2(x-1)x^{2k}.
   $$
My concern is this: For a direct sum decomposition, the kernel and the image must intersect trivially ($\ker(L) \cap \operatorname{im}(L) = \{0\}$). However, we can see that $\operatorname{im}(L)$ includes terms like $x^3$ (e.g., from $2(x-1)x^2$), which are odd and therefore also in $\ker(L)$. Doesn't this imply that the intersection of $\ker(L)$ and $\operatorname{im}(L)$ is nontrivial?
Thanks in advance for any help!

$2(x-1)x^{2}$ is not odd. Having odd terms in it is of no consequence.

Why is $x^3$ in $\operatorname{im}(L)$? Isn't every non-trivial polynomial in $\operatorname{im}(L)$ divisible by $x-1$?

$2(x-1)x^2$ contains the $x^3$ terms does not mean $x^3\in L(V)$. Vector addition closure only holds for both vectors in $L(V)$. In fact a necessary condition for $f\in L(V)$ is $f(1)=0$.
For example consider the vector space  $W=\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. You have $0=\textbf{i}-\textbf{i}\in\mathbb{R}$, but this does not mean $\textbf{i}\in\mathbb{R}$.
